# How to get rid of blue highlight box on drag for canvas in fabric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I just want to get rid of the blue highlight box that appears when you drag in the canvas while using fabric js.

I have searched up to get get rid of this but nothing appeared so far.
Only thing i tried is :

```css
#c{
-webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

but that doesn't work for canvas, only text

```js
//js part
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-260nw-668593321.jpg', function(img) {

  img.width = 200;
  img.height = 200;
  canvas.add(img);
  img.lockRotation = true;
  img.lockMovementX = true;
  img.lockMovementY = true;
  img.lockUniScaling = true;
  img.lockScalingY = true;
});
var panning = false;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
  panning = true;
  //style.cursor = "pointer";
  console.log("hhhhhhhh")
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  panning = false;
  console.log("babab")
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
  if (panning && e && e.e) {
    var units = 10;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
    canvas.relativePan(delta);
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom = zoom + delta / 400;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.zoomToPoint({
    x: opt.e.offsetX,
    y: opt.e.offsetY
  }, zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(opt) {
  var evt = opt.e;
  if (evt.altKey === true) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.selection = false;
    this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(opt) {
  if (this.isDragging) {
    var e = opt.e;
    this.viewportTransform[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
    this.viewportTransform[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
    this.requestRenderAll();
    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(opt) {
  this.isDragging = false;
  this.selection = true;
});
```

```css
#c {
  border: solid red 3px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

p {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<p>saddsa</p>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<style>

</style>
```

When you try to drag the canvas around, the blue highlight box shouldn't appear, how do I turn that off?

Reference: https://jsfiddle.net/dyjLaqk7/4/

EDIT: Thanks to Mark for the answer, here is the working version: https://jsfiddle.net/darrenz/wb7utjaf/69/
(line 27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `canvas.selection = false;` to `mouse:move` function.

```js
//js part
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-260nw-668593321.jpg', function(img) {

  img.width = 200;
  img.height = 200;
  canvas.add(img);
  img.lockRotation = true;
  img.lockMovementX = true;
  img.lockMovementY = true;
  img.lockUniScaling = true;
  img.lockScalingY = true;
});
var panning = false;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
  panning = true;
  //style.cursor = "pointer";
  console.log("hhhhhhhh")
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  panning = false;
  console.log("babab")
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
//turn off selection
canvas.selection = false;
  if (panning && e && e.e) {
    var units = 10;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
    canvas.relativePan(delta);
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom = zoom + delta / 400;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.zoomToPoint({
    x: opt.e.offsetX,
    y: opt.e.offsetY
  }, zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(opt) {
  var evt = opt.e;
  if (evt.altKey === true) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.selection = false;
    this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(opt) {
  if (this.isDragging) {
    var e = opt.e;
    this.viewportTransform[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
    this.viewportTransform[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
    this.requestRenderAll();
    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(opt) {
  this.isDragging = false;
  this.selection = true;
});
```

```css
#c {
  border: solid red 3px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

p {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<p>saddsa</p>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen questions similar to this. Try adding

```
    .noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
}
```

to your css, then adding the `.noselect` property to the canvas or whatever is being clicked on.

For example,

```
<p class="noselect">
  Unselectable element.
</p>
```

Comment: it does not work, the blue highlight box is still there when dragging in the white space of canvas